# Declaration of multiple variables?

Tags: swift, variables, constants, declaration

I stumbled upon this line of code and I do not get the meaning/function of this declared constant. I have never seen this before:

```
let (a, b, _) = someClassObject.someClassFunc(screenCenter, in: self.sceneView, objPos: focusSquare?.position)
```

The class this refers to looks like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    func someClassFunc(_ position: CGPoint, in sceneView: View, objPos: float, infinite: Bool = false) -> (position: float, number: int, testBool: Bool)
```

Even writing this question this looks incredible confusing to me, I do not get what is going on here.
So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is called [tuple destructuring](https://appventure.me/2015/07/19/tuples-swift-advanced-usage-best-practices/#sec-1-4)

Comment: I searched for multiple declaration etc haha. its so hard when you don't know what you are searching for. Thanks, that made it clear!